Are animals that can make facial expressions more visually communicative?
This is more like a shower thought but I was really interested in finding an answer. If this is the case, I would like sources that support this and gives reasons to why this may be the case. In the meantime, I'll try to find some evidence or a counterexample that disproves this and will post it on here. Thanks in advance.
Sources:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2826104/ -Emotional communication in primates: implications for neurobiology
Lisa A Parr,1 Bridget M Waller,2 and Jennifer Fugate3
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337975455_Differences_in_facial_expressions_during_positive_anticipation_and_frustration_in_dogs_awaiting_a_reward
"Therefore, this session was stopped and we only analysed positive and negative trials of the
Testing session (Step 4) for every subject." This line in the second article I mentioned may hinder the credibility of the experiment, reffering to not having a control case.

How do you measure whether an animal can make facial expressions? How do you measure the extent to which an animal is "visually communicative"? If making a facial expression is being visually communicative, isn't this a tautology?

Yeah, plenty of animals that communicate visually (though not necessarily by facial expression) including insects, fish, mammals, birds and reptiles. If the signal gets the point across, that's sufficient, so you can't make it more communicative...

@BryanKrause I apologize for leaving my question a bit vague. by "visually communicative" I meant animals that primarily uses visual clues(such as facial expressions and pointing) rather than using other forms such as smell or auditory clues. By facial expressions I meant shoving teeth for anger, "smiling"(though I've not seen it very much) when amused.

what attempt to answer this on your own have you done, you are expected to show some background research.

@John I have added sources I've researched to the "Sources:" part of my question.
